# What was my phone doing and why?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7. Yesterday and today it behaved very strangely. In the order I noticed things:

- it thought it was Thursday on Wednesday. I got reminders about appointments that had "already started", that sort of thing. I restarted and it now agreed it was Wednesday
- mail stopped coming in. (I use Outlook.) I didn't notice for some time, but looking at what mails I actually got that day, this was the next thing to happen
- mail stopped going out. I forwarded some emails to someone else who didn't get them
- when I typed a text, I could see the words I was typing, but they disappeared when I pressed Send and were not visible in the conversation. The recipient got the texts.
- when I received a text, I got the expected noise and could see the text contents in the notification at the top of the screen, but if I tapped it, the conversation did not update
- A hard power down fixed nothing

Throughout this, it worked fine as a phone (voice calls) and both Skype and WhatsApp worked perfectly. There is no doubt that I had data all the time. A game I play while waiting which insists on being connected worked fine, except for the first time when I came home and got on the wifi, where it would neither connect nor object that it couldn't connect. That's when I did the hard power down, left it 10 minutes, and powered it up again.

In the morning I sent a text and to my great surprise, what I typed stayed on the screen and I saw the reply too. However sending me pictures still did not work. Several hours later, emails started coming in and an hour or two after that the person I forwarded the emails to got them. And four or so hours after that, pictures in texts (multimedia messages) are happy to download and display.

Is there a single thing that can be wrong with a phone (and remember, it's not "you don't have data") that could cause this constellation of strange behaviours and magical self fixing?

There is plenty of storage space:

[image: view of the S7 as seen by my PC]

Comment: you should reboot your device more often

Comment: since reboots, both hard and soft, did not fix this, and the problems resolved without a reboot, what makes you suggest this, and how often do you think I reboot it now, @alecxs?

Comment: the issue is lack of memory, too much apps running in background. on my old samsung sometimes the keyboard didn't even print what i type. reboot once a day seems to be the best solution